# Methods inside a class, that use method inside same class on command line interpreter Python

Tags: python, self

For arguments sake if i have:

```
Class foo:
    def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

    def bah(self, arg)
        aString = self.bar("s1", "s2")
        return aString + arg3
```

I can use all and well within my code but if i want to test these individually on python command line not inside my script how would i go about doing this with the SELF, without the self all runs fine but i dont know how to supply the "self" while testing with the python command line tool (type python at command line)?

If i try to test in python command line tool i get:

```
>>>>from FILENAME import foo
>>>>print(foo.bah("ASTRING"))
missing 1 required positional argument
>>>>self.print(foo.bah("ASTRING"))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method by way of a instance of the class, also, `arg3` in `bah` is undefined:

```
Class foo:
    def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

    def bah(self, arg)
        arg3 = "SOMEVALL"
        aString = self.bar("s1", "s2")
        return aString + arg3
```

Then, in the shell:

```
from FILENAME import foo
print(foo().bah("SOMETHING"))
```

Comment: I see now thanks kindly foo().bah when using "self" not foo.bah.

Answer (score 1):

You must create an object, instance of `class foo`, and call `bah()` on it:

```
f = foo()
f.bah(some_arg)
```

you also need to correct the syntax of your class, and define `some_arg`

```
class foo:
    def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

    def bah(self, arg):
        aString = self.bar("s1", "s2")
        return aString + arg

some_arg = '123'
f = foo()
f.bah(some_arg)
```

#### output:

```
's1s2123'
```

Answer (score 1):

*you can create your function bounded to class by using classmethod decorator by inheriting from the base class object then making all the functions class bounded. you have nothing to change in your testing code. **an another way of looking the world***

```
    In [121]: class foo(object):
     ...:     @classmethod
     ...:     def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
     ...:         return arg1 + arg2
     ...:     @classmethod
     ...:     def bah(self, arg):
     ...:         arg3 = "SOMEVALL"
     ...:         aString = self.bar("s1", "s2")
     ...:         return aString + arg3
     ...:     

In [122]: print (foo.bah("have you learnt something new scott"))
s1s2SOMEVALL
```

Comment: I like this way of looking at the world ;)